# How to delete object in admin and keep parent?

Tags: django, model, admin, parent

I have following problem:

```
class Gift(models.Model):                                            
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='')

class ProblematicGift(Gift):
    # it does not help  gift_ptr = models.OneToOneField(Gift, parent_link=True, default=None, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    notes       = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='')
```

How I can delete the object of ProblematicGift in admin interface and keep the object of Gift ?

Simplified background: Automat select problematic gift and add it to table, where admin look at it, fix the gift and delete the ProblematicGift

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices:

1. Quickest and hackiest is to just create a new `Gift` based on `ProblematicGift` and then delete `ProblematicGift`.
2. You can use abstract inheritance to make `Gift` a primitive type and then subclass it to create `ProblematicGift`s and something like `GoodGifts`. The procedure after that is pretty much the same: they each get separate tables, so you add a `GoodGift` and then delete the `ProblematicGift`. It's pretty much the same as #1, but a little more semantic.
3. Is probably your best choice: using proxy models. You add an boolean attribute to gift of the form of something like 'is_problematic'. Then, create `ProblematicGift` as a proxy for `Gift` that automatically sets `is_problematic` to True on creation, and override the manager to only return gifts with `is_problematic` set to True. Then, you simply set that attribute to False instead of deleting `ProblematicGift` and it leaves the queryset.

--

```
class Gift(models.Model):
    name           = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='')
    notes          = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='')
    is_problematic = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class ProblematicGiftManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(ProblematicGiftManager, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs)
        return qs.filter(is_problematic=True)

class ProblematicGift(models.Model):

    objects        = ProblematicGiftManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Make sure it's new
        if not self.pk: 
            self.is_problematic = True

        super(ProblematicGift, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def resolve(self):
        self.is_problematic = False
        self.save()
```

**EDIT:** Moved `note` from `ProblematicGift` to `Gift`. When using proxy models, you can't add any new fields to the subclass.

Comment: only one question, how is ProblematicGift linked to Gift in this occurence ?

Comment: It's technically not "linked". It's an alias basically. `ProblematicGift` is setup as an easy way to access `Gift`s with `is_problematic`==True. It's basically still just `Gift` masquerading as a different object.

Comment: yes I understand :), but I have no clue how the query is maked from gift. In manager is maked query from ProblematicGift.  I tryed make meta.proxy=true and inherite, but I cannot use the field notes (this is understandable :-/)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was due to a hasty copy-paste job on my part. You can still use `note` but you have to move it to `Gift`. Since proxy models don't get their own tables, they can't add additional fields.

Comment: It's ok :) Problem is with the "note" it must stay in the problematicgift , because it is note about problem and should be deleted after it is solved. Note: there is bug in django wich should be usable in this case:) because when you inherite from proxy model, then the parent is not deleted, but I already reported the bug ..

Comment: That's not really a good reason to enforce that `note` only be on `ProblematicGift`. You can simply clear out the note field at the same time you unset the problematic flag. And if you don't want it to show up on regular `Gift` forms, that's as easy as adding it to `exclude`.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the mistake you're making is trying to inherit from `Gift`. You don't want to do that for your use case.

The best way is to make Gift a stand-alone model:

```
class Gift(models.Model):                                            
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='')
```

And then have ProblematicGift reference it:

```
class ProblematicGift(models.Model):
    gift = models.OneToOneField(Gift, null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='')

    # this method added based on a comment
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.gift.name
```

Now you can delete the ProblematicGift safely.

Comment: yes, I had it previsouly, but with this code I do not see the gift name directly in admin page. There is only link to the object and it is very hard to find the prooper gift in tons of records.

Comment: So define a `__unicode__` function. it can even be `return unicode(self.gift)`.

Comment: and is there way to edit this "name" in admin page for problematicgift ?